# C# List Blob Directory contents with a generator

Tags: c#, asynchronous, azure-blob-storage, yield-return

I'm working with azure blob storage, and want to make a method to list all the blobs within a directory. I can list all the elements of a directory like so:

```
CloudBlobDirectory dir;
BlobContinuationToken token = null;
List<IListBlobItem> elements = new List<IListBlobItem>();
do
{
    BlobResultSegment results = await dir.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(token);
    token = results.ContinuationToken;
    elements.AddRange(results.Results)
} while (token != null);
```

But I run into issues if I try to list all the contents with a generator. If I want to use `yield return`, Then the return type will have to be `IEnumerable<Task<IListBlobItem>>`, and then the method can't be `async`, and I can't use await.

```
public IEnumerable<Task<IListBlobItem>> ListDirectoryContents(CloudBlobDirectory dir)
{
    BlobContinuationToken token = null;
    List<IListBlobItem> elements = new List<IListBlobItem>();
    do
    {
        Task<BlobResultSegment> results = dir.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(token);
        ???
    } while (token != null);
}
```

In a non asynchronous method, how do I both update the continuation token and `yield return` each of the `IListBlobItem`s?

Comment: It might not help you now, but `yield await` and `foreach await` [will be available in C# 8](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1440/csharp-8-new-features).

Comment: Any particular reason you need to use the generator approach? What's wrong with the first method?